# Count number of selected row in gridpanel extjs

Tags: extjs, count, grid, store

I have a gridpanel with data, I can show the total number of records in the grid by `store.getcount()`. When I click a record, I would like to show the number of the selected record.

For example:

- The total number of records is 5
- I click the first row
- A textbox will show 1/5

Answer (score 3):

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getCount()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your grid select listener:

```
listeners:{
            select: function(selModel, record, index, options) {
                your_textfield.setValue(index+'/'+Ext.getCmp('yourGridId').store.getCount());
            }
        }
```